# Redefine an reference in Java (Extend usage)

Tags: java

I have a question about the usage of extend that I dont reach to understand.
For that example I'll use two classes:

```
public class Father {

    protected String message="Father";


    public void printme(){
        System.out.println(this.message);
    }
}
```

And

```
public final class Son extends Father {

    protected String message="Son";

}
```

My question is, why if I call:

```
new Son().printme();
```

It prints "Father"? How can I solve that changing only the "Son" class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Father` can't be final or `Son` couldn't subclass.

Comment: typo... remove final from Father

Answer (score 5):

Options:

- Override the `printme` method.
- Instead of declaring a new field in `Son`, change the value of the `Father` field (from `Son`, which you can do because it's protected - urgh)

Fields are *not* polymorphic. Code in `Father` which refers to the `message` field will *always* refer to the variable declared within `Father`.

I would strongly recommend that:

- You always make fields private, so in this case you'd also want to provide (say) a public getter and a protected setter within `Father`
- You *don't* shadow fields like this, partly because inexperienced developers *will* incorrectly assume that there's some sort of overriding going on

Answer (score 1):

Override printme() as well and define it as.

```
@Override public void printme(){
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

this.message in Father.printme() resolves to Father's message.

Answer (score 1):

Solved only by changing `son` class : (Note : `Father` cannot be `final`,hence changed )

```
public class Father {

protected String message="Father";


public void printme(){
    System.out.println(this.message);
}
}

final class Son extends Father {

protected String message="Son";
public void printme(){
    System.out.println(this.message);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the parent class, another option would be to change the field in the parent class to a method:

```
public class Father {
    protected String message() { return "Father"; }

    public void printme(){
        System.out.println(this.message());
    }
}

public final class Son extends Father {
    @Override
    protected String message() { return "Son"; }
}
```

Methods (unlike fields) are polymorphic, so this works as you'd like.